# Reporting Conditionals

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I'm wondering how to report Conditionals. Do we have to step back in terms of tenses?

I also found this https://www.englishcollege.com/conditionals-reported-speech-if-clause. As a native speaker can you agree with the explanations?

Examples (any conditionals)

> If you freeze water, it becomes solid.
>
> If it rains tomorrow, I'll take the car.
>
> If I lived closer to the cinema, I would go more often.
>
> If I had studied better, I would have passed the exam.

Reported speech (I changed nothing. Just added 'she said'. Are the sentences correct? :

> She said if you freeze water, it becomes solid.
>
> She said if it rains tomorrow, I'll take the car.
>
> She said if I lived closer to the cinema, I would go more often.
>
> She said if I had studied better, I would have passed the exam.

Comment: The one about freezing water is always true, so it can remain in the present tense.  The second depends on whether she said it earlier today, or on a different day (and is 'she' talking about herself, or you?).

Comment: Something's not right. "She said if it rains tomorrow, I'll take the car." How would she know? Did you mean "She said if it rains tomorrow, she'll take the car"?

Comment: It's clearer of you use a quotation: She said, "If it rains tomorrow, I'll take the car."

Comment: Your question needs clarification; you're not giving us enough information to answer. Suppose Mary says on Monday: "If it rains tomorrow, I'll take the car."  If you report what she said on Tuesday, you could say "Mary said that if it rains today, she'll take the car." If you report what she said on Wednesday, you could say "Mary said that if it had rained yesterday, she would have taken the car."

Comment: The reported speech is not relevant here for **your examples**.